# Failed to change gridview columns text with Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

```
$('#<%= gv.ClientID %> :submit[value=Apply]').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //***** THIS LINE*******//
    var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
    var oitemtemplate= row.children("td:eq(4)");
    var amt= row.children("td:eq(3)");              
    var noChild =  oitemtemplate.find('select[id$=ddlSubscribe]').val();
    childSelectedItems = new Array();
    childSelectedItems = noChild.split('|'); 
    amt.text(childSelectedItems[1]);

});
```

My gridview contain button for each row , and user will click this button to submit the changes value of dropdownlist in same row back to server, but before submitting to server i like to change the "amt" column's text to something else.

i'm not sure why "amt" column only change if i put this line event.preventDefault(); // THIS LINE******//. If remove this it's NOT working.

Please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One you use `event.preventDefault();` to prevent the default behavior of the submit button, you need to submit the form yourself.

```
$('#<%= gv.ClientID %> :submit[value=Apply]').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //***** THIS LINE*******//
    var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
    var oitemtemplate= row.children("td:eq(4)");
    var amt= row.children("td:eq(3)");              
    var noChild =  oitemtemplate.find('select[id$=ddlSubscribe]').val();
    childSelectedItems = new Array();
    childSelectedItems = noChild.split('|'); 
    amt.text(childSelectedItems[1]);
　　 $(this).closest('form').submit(); // submit the form.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The default action of the Submit button is to submit the form..

So when you click the button the changes are actually done and soon after that Form is submitted because of which there is a PostBack.. Once a postback occurs the HTML is rendered back to default HTML ..

So the changes are not reflected on the screen.

But when you include e.preventDefault()  , the default action is prevented and so no postback occurs..

That is the reason the changes are reflected this time..

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to `Page_Load` event, it causes ASP.NET to define `__doPostBack` javascript function

```
ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, string.Empty);
```

Then add this line to the click event

```
__doPostBack($(this).attr('name'), '');
```